# Event handling for PanZoom.js not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Using PanZoom JS, I am trying to handle a simple click event for any SVG that was clicked. According to docs, it should be as simple as this:

```
$panzoom.on('panzoomend', function(e, panzoom, matrix, changed) {
    if (changed) {
        // deal with drags or touch moves
    } else {
        // deal with clicks or taps
    }
});
```

This never fires and it never hits the if test.

Comment: We will need to see more code then, if this isn't firing at then some of the surrounding code has to be the problem, no this itself...

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create the $panzoom variable and call the panzoom.
You can enter something like this

```
var $panzoom = $('.panzoom').panzoom({
    contain: 'invert',
    minScale: 0.5,
    increment: 0.5,
});
```

after you can enter your code

```
$panzoom.on('panzoomend', function(e, panzoom, matrix, changed) {
    if (changed) {
        // deal with drags or touch moves
        alert("changed");
    } else {
        // deal with clicks or taps
        alert("not changed");
    }
});
```